# Weird Javascript For Loop Behaviour

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I've got a for loop like this:

```
for (var i=first; i<=last; i++)
{
    $("#markers").append("<div class='marker'>"+i+"</div>");
}
```

`first` is set to 2001 and `last` is 2010. This works fine. The problem is when I change it to:

```
for (var i=first; i<=last; i+=1)
{
     $("#markers").append("<div class='marker'>"+i+"</div>");
}
```

(Notice the different final declaration is different). Any variation other than `i++` results in an infinite loop. It's very strange as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuEa2/1/) with the same parameters works happily. Any suggestions?

Comment: it seem to work under Chrome. Wich browser have you tried?

Comment: Curious: why would you do i+=1 instead of i++ in the first place? Seems like it's more work than it needs to be.

Comment: I actually needed to do `i+=some_variable`, I'd just simplified it down for the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess that `first` is set in a way that ambiguously could be interpreted as a `string`. So the first version can only be interpreted as increment, but the second is being interpreted by javascript as string concatenation.

Comment: Does that mean this is the **answer**? :-)

Comment: It did however I wasn't in front of the computer after the 10 minute limit expired. Not my first rodeo. Thanks for the great answer though!

Comment: Thanks. I knew that from your reputation. I was just enjoying my first good answer.